# Is $T$ uniformly continous?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $(X,\lVert \cdot\lVert)$ be a normed space. Let $T$ be a function given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cccc}
T:&X&\longrightarrow&X\\
  &x&\longmapsto&T(x)=x\lVert x\lVert.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Is $T$ uniformly continous?

My answer is yes. Let $(x_n),(y_n)$ sequences in $X$ such that $\lVert x_n-y_n\lVert\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}0$. I need to prove that $\lVert T(x_n)-T(y_n)\lVert\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}0$. Indeed,
\begin{equation}
\lVert T(x_n)-T(y_n)\lVert=\lVert \lVert x_n\lVert x_n-\lVert y_n\lVert y_n\lVert\leq (\lVert x_n\lVert+\lVert y_n\lVert)\lVert x_n-y_n\lVert\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}(2\lVert x_n\lVert)\cdot0=0.
\end{equation}
However, I could find a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $\lVert x_n\lVert\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}+\infty$ but I'm not sure if that sequence exists.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hint: try considering this function on a one-dimensional subspace $\operatorname{span}(v)$. If $T$ is uniformly continuous, then it will be uniformly continuous on this subspace, and hence the map $t \mapsto T(tv)$ will be uniformly continuous. What does this map simplify to? Is it uniformly continuous?

Comment: Or consider the case $X=\mathbb R$, so $T(x)=x|x|,\,x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\|x_0\|=1$. Let $x_n =nx_0, y_n=(n+\frac 1 n)x_0$. Show that $\|x_n-y_n\|=\frac 1 n$ and $\|Tx_n-Ty_n\|=\|2x_0+\frac  1{n^{2}}x_0\| \to 2$. What does this say about uniform continuity?